# Counting from multiple tables and return all count values in one query slow

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I want to counting from multiple tables and return all count values in one query. I've created  SQL and It feels like this query is slow. Is this the best way to do as i said? If not, please suggest me for better solutions. Because sometimes it took more than 15 seconds to finish querying. Thank you.

And here is my database approximate info.
table `post` 400 rows.
table `comment` 3000 rows.
table `like` 1000 rows.
table `view` 6000 rows.

SQL

```
SELECT p.*,
     COUNT(c.id) as commentCount,
     COUNT(l.id) as likeCount,
     COUNT(c.id) as viewCount,
FROM post p
     LEFT JOIN comment c
           ON (p.id = c.postid) 
     LEFT JOIN like l
           ON (p.id = l.postid) 
     LEFT JOIN view v
           ON (p.id = v.postid) 
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY postCount DESC
```

TABLE post

```
CREATE TABLE `post` (
`id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`details` VARCHAR( 500 ) NOT NULL ,
`datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

TABLE comment

```
CREATE TABLE `comment ` (
`id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`postid` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
`details` VARCHAR( 500 ) NOT NULL ,
`datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

TABLE like

```
CREATE TABLE `like` (
`id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`postid` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
`datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

TABLE view

```
CREATE TABLE `view` (
`id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`postid` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
`ip` VARCHAR( 30) NOT NULL ,
`datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

Comment: You will definitely get much better performance if you create indexes on `postid` column in each table (comment, like,view). Also, it is usually better to avoid naming tables/columns using reserved words.

Comment: I think primary key is an indexes, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, primary key always has underlying unique index. However, `view.postid` is not a PK (neither are `like.postid`, `comment.postid`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is slow because you are aggregating along multiple dimensions.  This greatly multiplies the size of the data.  One solution is to pre-aggregate the data:

```
SELECT p.*, c.cnt as commentCount, l.cnt as likeCount, v.cnt as viewCount,
FROM post p LEFT JOIN
     (select c.postid, count(*) as cnt
      from comment c
      group by c.postid
     ) c
     ON p.id = c.postid LEFT JOIN
     (select l.postid, count(*) as cnt
      from like l
      group by l.postid
     ) l
     ON p.id = l.postid LEFT JOIN
     (select v.postid, count(*) as cnt
      from view v
      group by v.postid
     ) v
     ON p.id = v.postid
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY postCount DESC;
```

In addition, your query would return about the same values for the three counts -- and they would probably not be accurate.